# JSON api works on local, but not on public deploy

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a weather API using JSON that works on my local machine, but when I try to deploy it to GithubPages, it nulls out and the API doesn't pull. It was written in js for a reactjs page.

[Here is the working site that is on localhost:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfCxB.png)

[Not working website hosted on GitHub pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQxd7.png)

[Deployed Website](https://samuelpianoguy.github.io/portfolio/)

```
state = {
    current: 'none'
}

fetchWeather = () => {
return fetch(`https://api.aerisapi.com/observations/75248client_id=${accessId}&client_secret=${APIkey}`)
.then((res) => res.json())
}

componentDidMount = () => {
this.fetchWeather()
.then((json) => {
  json.success ? this.setState({ current: json.response.ob }) : null
})
}

formatCurrentWeather = (currentWeather) => {
let current = ''
if (currentWeather.toLowerCase().charAt(currentWeather.length-1) === 'y') {
  current = currentWeather.toLowerCase() + ' '
} else if (currentWeather.toLowerCase() === 'clear') {
  current = 'cloudless '
} else if (currentWeather.toLowerCase() === 'freezing fog') {
  current = 'freezing '
} else if (currentWeather.toLowerCase().charAt(currentWeather.length-1) === 'g') {
  current = currentWeather.toLowerCase() + 'gy '
} else {
  current = currentWeather.toLowerCase() + 'y '
}
return current
}

importAll = (r) => {
let icons = {};
r.keys().map((item, index) => { icons[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
return icons;
}

render() {
console.log(this.state.current)
const icons = this.importAll(require.context('../images/icons', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
let currentWeather = ''
this.state.current === 'none' ? null : currentWeather = this.formatCurrentWeather(this.state.current.weatherPrimary)
```

Comment: GET https://api.aerisapi.com/observations/75248?client_id=6x2JBo3WVT2uY5KpNaNcS&client_secret=pDFdHOyWZRPzmKvKCWgQIIFZ4eM6dxyFgNvgaU6A
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 250ms]
JSON 
success false
error {…}
code unauthorized_namespace
description The request was made from outside the allowed namespace for the client.
response []
Response payload
{"success":false,"error":{"code":"unauthorized_namespace","description":"The request was made from outside the allowed namespace for the client."},"response":[]}
This is the request you are sending. Are you sure you dont need auth token to access this api ?

Comment: https://www.aerisweather.com/blog/2017/05/03/protecting-aeris-api-credentials/

Comment: I am using an access id and an API key. Could you explain how you are seeing this error message?

Comment: you open developer console (CTRL+SHIFT+I) in Firefox and go to your page. In console there is network tab in which you can see your request to weather service and clicki on it you will able to see what response from server you've got.